# Get permissions in the facebook admininterface without a legal company

Tags: facebook

How can I get an access token and an app token?
I have registered my app through this site https://developers.facebook.com/ I chose "business"

What do I want?

I want to get an access to posts of groups/users and comments. At first itll be enough if I will have an access only to open pages. Im not a company and when I tried to get it through the graph api (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) I got the following error 'This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_user_content' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature'. I chose these items(Facebook App->my app; User or Page->App token).

I tried to get these permissions in the admin interface of my app in FB in this section "Permissions and Features". Having send these requests it was written "You will need to complete this step in addition to App Review before you can access live data.
Business verification: You'll need to connect your app to a Facebook Business Manager account and upload an official document showing your business or organization's name and physical address.".
As I mentioned before Im not a company. May someone recommend me what to do next? Should I create a new app and choose something else instead of "Business"? Or should I send a request to the FBs support and explain to them my situation, if "yes", how can I find this support contacts? Actually I didnt find support contacts on their site, only the community form and their support associated with payment questions.

I tried to ask in their official community, but they didnt answer for 17 days
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/224348066049560/?post_id=224348069382893

Comment: You will not be able to access any “live” data, before you have not submitted your app for review. For testing/development, you will need to work with user accounts added to a role in the app, your app will only be able to interact with content created by those accounts.

Comment: As for which app type to chose to begin with, they have a whole documentation page explaining the differences, and which type will have access to what – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/app-types